# working of comparator function in priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I don't understand the sorting order set by the comparator function.

This is the code of the comparator parameter passed to the priority queue:

```
struct CompareHeight { 
    bool operator()(Person const& p1, Person const& p2) 
    {  
        return p1.height < p2.height; 
    } 
};
```

This is giving output in decreasing order of height

example output: 6 5 4 3 2

Shouldn't be output like : 2 3 4 5 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `priority_queue` always starts with the largest element (highest priority), see e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/).

Answer (score 0):

As a comparator function, the question will be "Does the first argument come before the second argument in our order?" (According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)). Therefore, if you want to sort it according to ascending order, you should compare `p1.height > p2.height`.

Normally, your original code would work, however, since this is a priority queue, the order will be opposite (as in `p1.height > p2.height`).